# Alternative to WITH AS in this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

So my main criteria is to just ditch the WITH AS, a report wont allow me to use WITH AS unfortunately.  Here's the SQL:

```
;WITH table1 AS 
    (SELECT 
    tbl_.ticketsid 
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE= 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Closed
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Pending
FROM
    "tickets" "tbl_" 
    LEFT JOIN "fields" "tbl_f" ON "tbl_"."ticketsid" = "tbl_f"."ticketsid" 
    LEFT JOIN "taskinfo" "tbl_t" ON "tbl_"."ticketsid" = "tbl_t"."ticketsid"
    LEFT JOIN TaskDetails td ON td.TASKID=tbl_t.TASKID
    GROUP BY tbl_.ticketsid
    )

SELECT DISTINCT
    "tbl_"."ticketsid" AS "Ticket ID", 
    "tbl_"."TITLE" AS "Title", 
    CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, tbl_.OPENED/1000, '1970/1/1') AS DATE) OpenDate,
    "tbl_f"."UDF_CHAR13" AS "Category"
    ,t.Closed
    ,t.Pending
FROM
    "ticketsid" "tbl_" 
    FULL JOIN "fields" "tbl_f" ON "tbl_"."ticketsid" = "tbl_f"."ticketsid" 
    FULL JOIN "taskinfo" "tbl_t" ON "tbl_"."ticketsid" = "tbl_t"."ticketsid"
    FULL JOIN table1 t ON tbl_.ticketsid = t.ticketsid
WHERE
    TEMPLATEID = '123'
```

I can't really figure out how to escape WITH AS, I've tried using selects but my results to get duplicated and spam my output.

Comment: That semicolon is a statement terminator, not a beginninator. It may very well be that your reporting tool doesn't like multiple statements. You could try simply removing that semicolon. If that doesn't work just move your cte to a subquery.

Comment: A Common Table Expression is not a *requirement*, just replace it as a derived table.

Comment: Slight detour....date literals should always be in the format of YYYYMMDD or they can get interpreted incorrectly.,

Comment: Why all the `FULL JOIN`s here when the value of `TEMPLATEID` *must* be a non-`NULL` value?

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the CTE into a derived/nested table, this is semantically equivalent.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    "tbl_"."ticketsid" AS "Ticket ID", 
    "tbl_"."TITLE" AS "Title", 
    CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, tbl_.OPENED/1000, '1970/1/1') AS DATE) OpenDate,
    "tbl_f"."UDF_CHAR13" AS "Category"
    ,t.Closed
    ,t.Pending
FROM
    "ticketsid" "tbl_" 
    FULL JOIN "fields" "tbl_f" ON "tbl_"."ticketsid" = "tbl_f"."ticketsid" 
    FULL JOIN "taskinfo" "tbl_t" ON "tbl_"."ticketsid" = "tbl_t"."ticketsid"
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT 
            tbl_.ticketsid 
            ,COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE= 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Closed
            ,COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Pending
        FROM
            "tickets" "tbl_" 
            LEFT JOIN "fields" "tbl_f" ON "tbl_"."ticketsid" = "tbl_f"."ticketsid" 
            LEFT JOIN "taskinfo" "tbl_t" ON "tbl_"."ticketsid" = "tbl_t"."ticketsid"
            LEFT JOIN TaskDetails td ON td.TASKID=tbl_t.TASKID
            GROUP BY tbl_.ticketsid
    ) t ON tbl_.ticketsid = t.ticketsid
WHERE
    TEMPLATEID = '123'
```

I can't tell you the validity of the results. In particular

- The use of `DISTINCT` is usuall a code-smell: it indicates the joins are poorly thought through, and should possibly be `EXISTS` or use a `GROUP BY`.
- The self-join could probably be replace with window functions, for example `COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE = 3 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ticketsid)`
- The use of `FULL JOIN` is also strange, especially given the self-join. WHy do you expect results from only one side of the join?